# Mapping Bronx Breweries 1840-1940?

Tags: leaflet, carto, wordpress

I created on a Wordpress site for my final thesis and need to add a map. I do not even know where to start.  I am so confused.  I do not need to do anything fancy (yet)  I just want to map about 30 spots in the South Bronx.
I was using leaflet but I was told that Carto was the way to go.

I found this https://jsmit8.carto.com/tables/breweries/public/map
It has current breweries.  I want to create a map with the breweries that no longer exist.

Comment: The answer on the duplicate suggests using the Leaflet Maps Marker Wordpress Plugin.